# Iphone: Is there a way to consolidate or collect data of all the notifications in the notifications center?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on the notifications and want to collect/store them in a place. Is there a way to interact with notification center and collect them?

Comment: Are you talking about just your app’s notifications or are you trying to gather other apps’ as well? The latter there’s no API for, for security and privacy reasons; for the former, you’re better off talking to whatever web service you sent the notifications from in the first place and pulling down whatever you’d like to consider the user’s “inbox”.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: The intention is to collect notifications from Whatsapp/facebook/twitter and store them in one place. 
Or does Notification center has a back up?

Comment: Yup, absolutely no way to do that. A malicious app could use that ability to harvest personal information.

Comment: Malicious app? are you saying that I can make for myself to hack my notifications?